# Call JavaScript function on drop successfully

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I am using Telerik Kendo UI in ASP.NET MVC.

I have implemented [linked list](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/linkedlists) please look into this for better understand of my question.

Now I want to call the JavaScript function on drop successfully in one from both.

Comment: Someone who don't know the answer please don't reduce it to down if know the answer or any mistake please mention it. thanks

Comment: most mark downs are caused because it's looks like the person hasn't attempted to solve the problem on their own first. Generally if you show the solution that you have tried but doesn't work then the community is usually willing to help you correct your approach or suggest better approaches.

Indent all code by 4 spaces and it will format correctly. Good luck

Comment: Set `.Events(events => events.End("onEnd"))` on both in your view and create a function named `onEnd` in javascript to capture it

Comment: @hsh Thanks for comment I tried in kendo style and got what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer and eager to post:

So here is the answer:

I just add end: function inside the kendoSortable.

```
$("#sortable-listD").kendoSortable({
                connectWith: "#sortable-listC",
                placeholder: placeholder,
                end: function (e) {
// Here I can do my code or whatever.
                }
            });
```

I am in confuse and shock as well that Kendo has not provided such code but still I got from other link from kendo itself.

Thanks to hsh also for comment.